# Erro ao tentar implementar Classe tipo abstrata de dados

Tags: java

Preciso implementar uma TAD no repl.it, mas dá o seguinte erro:

Error: Could not find or load main class Main
exit status 1

```
import java.lang.Math;

class Ponto {

  public int x;

  public int y;

  public Ponto(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

  }

  public boolean igual(Ponto p) {
    return this.x == p.x && this.y == p.y;

  }

  public String texto() {
    return (this.x + " " + this.y);
  }

  public double distancia(Ponto p) {
    double d1 = this.x - p.x;
    double d2 = this.y - p.y;
    return Math.sqrt((d1*d1)+(d2*d2));
  }

  public void translada(int dx, int dy) {
    this.x = this.x+dx;
    this.y = this.y+dy;

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
   Ponto ponto = new Ponto(2, 3);
   String texto = ponto.texto();
   System.out.println(texto); // Imprime (2, 3);

  }
}
```

Comment: Implementei daquela forma e está dando erro.

Comment: Seria interessante então questionar o autor da resposta comentando, ainda mais se a resposta dele está com problemas.

Comment: @Articuno o problema é a reputação do Samarone. Ele não possui poder de comentar em posts alheios ainda. Então eu ACHO que nesse caso pode ser re-aberta, alterando a pergunta com a tentativa frustrada.

Comment: @mutlei o problema é que ele criou outro perfil pra fazer essa pergunta, ao inves de usar o que fez a outra,  é o mesmo usuário, com o outro perfil ele conseguiria comentar, como criador dela.

Comment: Entendido @Articuno

Comment: Estou desesperado pessoal, fui me meter em fazer uma faculdade de ADS e não tenho menor afinidade com algoritmos, já terminei o curso porem uma DP de estrutura de dados vem me acompanhando a tempos, só quero terminar essa faculdade e ver se eu consigo alguma coisa melhor na área de infra que é o que eu faço atualmente.